# Symfony2, difference between isValid() and $this->get('validator')

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm new in Symfony2 and I wish to know what's the difference of validate a form between:

```
$form->isValid()
```

and

```
$this->get('validator')->validate($form->getData())
```

using validation rules in validations.yml

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The validator, in your case, checks object to which the form was bound. The [`Form::isValid()`](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L738) method, besides, checks a form status (whether the form was submitted, whether it was disabled).